# Mercurial: restore files

Tags: mercurial

I'd like to restore a file that has been deleted in some commit, and restore it under a different name, so that it shares the history. In subversion, I'd do

```
svn cp src@REV dest
```

i.e. use peg revisions. What's the equivalent in Mercurial?

Comment: I don't believe that hg can track a file's history between renames directly. Interesting question though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think Mercurial has a built-in way to do this.  But I think you can get the same effect via:

```
hg up -C REV # Update to revision containing a copy of the file
<modify the file in question>
hg commit  # Create second head based on old revision
hg merge # Merge two heads into one
# Note: make sure to choose to have the file exist
hg commit
hg mv MYFILE MYNEWNAME
```

This will have the file keep all its old history, as best Mercurial can track it.

Comment: I'd've done the 'mv' before the merge, in the new unnamed branch, but the end result is the same.

Comment: That worked fine for me, with Ry4an's recommendation to just move the file where your procedure suggests "<modify the file in question>".

Answer (score 7):

Wouldn't just (if you "`hg remove`"d src in REV+1):

```
hg revert -rREV src
hg status
A src
hg rename src dest
hg commit -m"restored src and renamed it to dest"
```

work?

**edited**: I just tested it and it seems to be ok. Actually no "`hg add`" is necessary for src as revert is taking care of this. However if you do just one commit instead of two (like in the code above), hg will give a warning:

> src has not been committed yet, so no
>   copy data will be stored for dest.

Hope it'll help.

Comment: That would work to restore the file; it doesn't allow simultaneous renaming (since the added file is not considered having a history). However, with two commits, this would have worked as well.